# What's the Twitter error "Your account may not be allowed to perform this action. Please refresh the page and try again."

Tags: twitter

A) I get a very bizarre error sometimes, when I'm trying to submit a tweet:

> Your account may not be allowed to perform this action. Please refresh the page and try again.

This is very frustrating, because the message is within the 140 character limit, and there's no specific reason as to why Twitter is rejecting the tweet. Is it because there's more than 1 link in a tweet? Is it because there's a shortened link formatted incorrectly? I've also noticed that prefixing "http" to a link, jumps the char count by 5+5.

B) It looks like Twitter's extremely broken. Is there another tool, like Tumblr, that basically integrates well with Twitter feeds?

Comment: You might get more help sending a DM to [@support](http://twitter.com/support). It seems that you are not the only one having [this](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3573) (or [similar](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/577)) problem.

Comment: Yes, those are posts that I have looked at. But they don't solve the problem, and a user on the forum (dev.twitter.com), directs the user to post his question to 'support.twitter.com'. I haven't gotten any word back from them yet. 

I've seen that other people are having similar problems, but don't have any word on what the actual problem is, or when it's going to be fixed. I thought I would ask around.

Comment: I get this error frequently when tweeting OR when starring a tweet, or retweeting something, or something. It's hell of annoying.

Comment: Where are you attempting to post the tweet from? Twitter.com, m.twitter.com, official twitter app, third-party twitter app, your own twitter app?

Answer (score 4):

If you disable the "REFERER" HTTP feature (like, as in my case, via the convenient checkbox in the Firefox "Preferences Toolbar" add-on), you get this error. Re-enable the feature and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever anything that was re-tweeted by someone I follow, that originated from a certain Twitter user, I see,

> Sorry you are not authorized to see this status

if I try to click on any link in the message.

[image: Nouriel Roubini blocked me]

I receive the message that you referenced,

> Your account may not be allowed to perform this action

when I try to follow that particular Twitter user.

See too, **[corroborating evidence on dev.twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/7759)** submitted by a Twitter user who was blocked by @MrsPaxil.